# Preventing Curl From Timing Out when transferring a large file

Tags: php, curl

I have a 25 second timeout on my PHP Curl Opts.  If it goes over that I get the error:

```
Operation timed out after 25000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
```

Sometimes though I get an error that makes it seem like it's timing out while it's downloading the file like so.

```
Operation timed out after 25000 milliseconds with 196879 bytes received
```

Is there a way to make Curl extend the timeout if it's downloading data?  Or am I reading this wrong and it has waited 25 seconds since receiving the last data?

The settings are as follows:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,3); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 25);
```

Thanks

Comment: From php.net: `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT  The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect. Use 0 to wait indefinitely.` [source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: I'm not concerned with the connection timeout.  You get a different error if it fails to connect.

Comment: [This page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) explains the meaning of `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`.

Comment: And in addition to what @DarkBee said -http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT: The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute. So it will die in mid operation after 25 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Set the curl timeouts to 0 to avoid timing out all together

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,0);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that means it will hang forever if the other end doesn't return an error.